# Using authentication for MS Office Documents on WebDAV

Tags: javascript, authentication, ms-office, webdav

I want to create a webpage which shows MS Word documents and are read-write accessible through authentication.

I have a WebDAV Server running with some MS Word documents on, when i put the following code it opens the documents in read-write mode in Internet Explorer 9

```html
<a href="http://server/webdav/document.doc">Edit document</a>
```

with Internet Exploerer 8 and below I use the following Javascript code:

```js
new ActiveXObject("SharePoint.OpenDocuments.3").EditDocument("http://server/webdav/document.doc");
```

This works just fine.
Now my problem is that i want to use authentication.

I would use the following syntax but Internet Explorer doesnt allow this.
see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

```html
<a href="http://username:password@server/webdav/document.doc">Edit document</a>
```

I already tried to change the registry to allow these kind of links like its described in the microsoft support document but with no use in Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 9.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server must support one of the following authentication protocols: 
Basic, Digest, NTLM or Kerberos. Hypothetically MS Office 2007 SP1 and later versions also support Forms/cookies authentication.

Microsoft Office (and Mini-redirector) will display the login dialog when necessary, you do not need to pass the credentials in the Url.